# CSS inline-block and width-auto incorrect in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, width

So i have this weird behaviour in Internet Exlporer 9-11 and EDGE (Spartan).

In all browsers now i see my example like this (which is desired):
[image]

In Internet Explorers i see it like this:
[image]

Before i had this stuff pretty much everywhere except Firefox, until i added:

```
svg {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

This fixed problem everywhere, except IE...

Here's working simplified example that you can tweak:
http://codepen.io/failure13/pen/waxaOx

For myself i have no idea, i absolutely have no idea how IE behave here and calculates width: auto; based on what values...
I always thought it should be parent or element height itself.

I tried everything that came in my head for now.
I see no logic, so this seem to be some nasty bug.

If so, maybe there's workaround?
I really need it, coz i really don't want to use fixed width values (of course it will fix problem, but it's not solution).

Thanks in advance to everybody who may help with it, let's make web better place!

Comment: have you got <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> as the first line of your meta descriptions?

Comment: No, what does this meta means?

Comment: read this article https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible

Comment: Oh, it's nice to know! Thx for the tip! But it ain't helped with my issue :(

Comment: you would be better off sizing your image (a png preferably, optimized - try tinypng.com) to a percentage of your header instead of having it width svg width 100% your image is obviously 300 pixels wide in its raw state. thats what is causing the problem i think

Comment: My svg is obviously 48x48px in it's raw state...And i see no logic why it should be 300px in IE... It's not image (must be svg) and not header, it's part of complex framework and could be in a lot of elements, so i need flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

in your class

```
.svg-flex {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

change the `width` to `max-width:72px;` 
this works in ie 11 anyway. I checked

here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOjNrN

Comment: Sure thing, it works everywhere, just as hardcoded width on svg element itself!) But sadly it's not an option, coz max-width shouldn't be hardcoded, the only way i want to control this whole situation is be setting height on parent div...So i would need something like percentages or unitless or ems in max-width rule, which would equal to height of parent div...I could do something like height: 0; padding-top: 100%; technique, but sad part is that svg could have non-square proportions, therefore i just need width: auto to work in ie without making it x4.16 times higher for voodoo reasons...

Comment: Basicly i need to understand for what reasons even modern IE threats this svg width: auto; as there would be lot more content than in reality, from where does it get those additional numbers? I was trying to reset everything from font-size and line-height to paddings, margins, borders etc (which seemed logical, for how usually box-model inconsistencies grow) and i couldn't find an answer..